# JqueryUI Autocomplete : only one character is displayed per list item

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I'm using `jquery-1.4.2.min` and `jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom` to get the autocomplete data on a jsp page, here is the code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("input#airportfrom").autocomplete({minLength: 3,
source: function(request, response) { $.ajax({ 
url: "MLocationLookupSearchPopUpAuto.action?LANGUAGE=${param.LANGUAGE}&SITE=${param.SITE}&RESULT_FILTER=3",
dataType:"text/html", 
data: { MATCH : $("#airportfrom").val() }, 
success: function(data) { response(data); } }); } }); });
```

The result returned is correct as I have used an `alert(data);` inside the success function and it gave correct result, but in the  list, it is showing one character or one alphabet per line, hence if I want to get LONDON, it is displayed as:

```
l
o
n
d
o
n
```

Any idea why this happening ? Whether we have to give data as json only because here I'm getting the data from a jsp.

Comment: i mean london is displayed as:                                        l                                                                   o                                                                   n                                                                   d                                                                   o                                                                   n    .....i.e not a single result but six different results

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the response data into lines using "\n"

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: function(request,response) {
                    $.ajax({
                    dataType: "text",
                    url: 'yourscript.php?extraParam=foo',
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                         var lines = data.split("\n");
                         response(lines);
                    }
                })}
        });
```

Comment: This gives me Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'split', Since its an object

Comment: +1, this answer helped me with the same problem. In my script I printed all results with a comma (,) between each result en then split the data on the comma.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was down to serializing the object twice (by mistake) on the server side. The JSON data returned to the client was being de-serialized to a string rather than an array.