# JQuery AutoComplete Firing but only single letter per line

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I saw a similar question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525279/jqueryui-autocomplete-only-one-character-is-displayed-per-list-item), but the answer did not help me.

I call this:

```
$("#Location" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({ url: "searchAutoComplete.asp?Location=all",
            data: { term: $("#Location").val()},
            dataType: "TEXT",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
            response(data);
            //response(eval('[' + data + ']');
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

My results end up looking like this:

```
A
P
P
L
E  
,
B
A
N
A
N
A
```

How do I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the `response` function do?  What does `data` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source callback needs to be invoked with an array of strings, not a string. If you response contains a comma separated string, you should split it and pass the resulting array to `response`:

```
response(data.split(","));
```

Comment: You are a rockstar! Thanks